# django: chaining add filter in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

How to chain the "add" filter in templates?

This does not work, nothing is displayed:

```
{% with obj_ids=obj1.pk|add:"-"|add:obj2.pk %}
   <td>{{ obj_ids}}</td>
{% endwith %}
```

While having just one add works:

```
{% with obj_ids=obj1.pk|add:obj2.pk %}
   <td>{{ obj_ids}}</td>
{% endwith %}
```

Thanks

Comment: This might not be possible. I think it might be good idea to do it in the view itself instead of in template. Look forward for seeing solution though if any.

Answer (score 0):

If one works, wrapping with 2 withs must work too?

```
{% with obj_ids=obj1.pk|add:"-" %}
    {% with obj_ids_2=obj_ids|add:obj2.pk %}
       <td>{{ obj_ids_2 }}</td>
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

This kind of thing is why I enjoy Jinja over django's templates. Install coffin and you can do this:

```
{{ '%s-%s' % (obj1.pk, obj2.pk) }}
{{ '-'|join([obj1.pk, obj2.pk]) }}
```

Much more readable, and still keeps separation from view/template.

Answer (score 0):

Right, Jinja looks better for this kind of things.

In the meanwhile, I created a custom filter but I could not make it work with several arguments using *args so I have to call it twice.

```
@register.filter(name='concat')
def concat(value, arg):
    return '{}{}'.format(value, arg)
```